# stack bars with stat_binline()

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggridges

I have data similar to the example below.

I am wanting to visualise the spread of the outcome variable (`value`) for each group (`name`). The fill aesthetic is the desired interval - the example below uses the interquartile range.

I would expect the `position="identity"` to stack the bars on top of each other for the fill aesthetic ([as it does for geom_bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11604070/issue-with-ggplot2-geom-bar-and-position-dodge-stacked-has-correct-y-values)). This is the behaviour that I want.

When I try position="stack", it's a mess.

I have looked at the [stat_binline examples](https://rdrr.io/cran/ggridges/man/stat_binline.html) and the [ggridges vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggridges/vignettes/introduction.html) but neither have examples where the position is modified to stack the ridges (binned or not).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggridges)
set.seed(123)

size <- 1000
data.frame(
  name=sample(LETTERS[1:5], size=size, replace=T),
  value=c(sample(1:20, size=size*0.8, replace=T), rep(15, size*0.2))
) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  arrange(value) %>%
  mutate(percentile=row_number()/n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(in_interval=percentile > 0.25 & percentile < 0.75)%>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value, y = name, height = stat(count), fill=in_interval)) +
  stat_binline(position = "identity", alpha=0.3, bins=20, scale=0.9) +
  coord_flip()
```

The overlap that I want to avoid is shown here. I want these bars to the stacked instead.

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: "stack" leads to nice art! and this message "Stacking not well defined when not anchored on the axis".

Comment: Very nice art indeed! Is there any way to anchor to the axis for this geom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reviewed the ggridges docs - https://wilkelab.org/ggridges/reference/stat_binline.html

The ggplot position page - https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/position_stack.html

And a few of the great [ggridges] tagged answers on SO -

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58557352/10276092

[Add color gradient to ridgelines according to height](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68955883/10276092)

And all I've produced is a non-ggridges answer:

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=value, fill=in_interval)) +
  geom_histogram(bins=20) +      
  facet_grid(cols=vars(name)) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @M.Viking! This will be my backup solution if I can't figure out the ggridges approach. I'd prefer the plots to be within the space rather than separate facets.

Comment: Did you figure the ggridges solution? I am having the same problem.